# Why don't developers pass arguments directly to setOnCheckedChangeListener

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to Android.
Here's the code:

```
Switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
// do something}
```

I've done some coding in C++ so I know I must invoke it like this

```
variable = OnCheckedChangeListener    
Switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener**(variable)** { _, isChecked ->
        // do something}
```

I don't know why the function works without me passing in any argument.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You are passing in an argument. The `{ _, isChecked -> ... }` part is an argument, in the form of a lambda expression.

Comment: I've traced this strange hierachy of inheritance. Would you please tell me if I am correct. setOnCheckedChangeListener requires OnCheckedChangeListener as its parameter. OnCheckedChangeListener is an interface, which is in reality just a function. You end up passing this function as an argument to setOnCheckedChangeListener.

Comment: "OnCheckedChangeListener is an interface, which is in reality just a function" -- not exactly, but you are close. `OnCheckedChangeListener` has a single abstract function in its interface definition. Kotlin supports [creating instances of such an interface from a lambda expression or other function type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look into the source-code for the `Switch` view, the `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` method is defined like this:

```
fun setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener: CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener?) {
    mOnCheckedChangeListener = listener
}
```

It does expect an argument, in the form of an interface `OnCheckedChangeListener`, whose definition looks like this:

```kotlin
interface OnCheckedChangeListener {
    fun onCheckedChanged(buttonView: CompoundButton?, isChecked: Boolean)
}
```

It has only one method. An interface with only one abstract method is called a functional interface, or a Single Abstract Method (SAM) interface.

For functional interfaces, you can use SAM conversions that help make your code more concise and readable by using lambda expressions.

Instead of creating a class that implements a functional interface manually, you can use a lambda expression. With a SAM conversion, Kotlin can convert any lambda expression whose signature matches the signature of the interface's single method into an instance of a class that implements the interface.

So the reason why you don't have to pass in an instance of `OnCheckedChangeListener`, is because of syntactic sugar, Kotlin allows you to just define the body of the method that is described by the interface, and it will create and pass the argument behind the scenes.

If you wanted to do it yourself, it would look like this:

```
switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(object : OnCheckedChangeListener {
    override fun onCheckedChanged(buttonView: CompoundButton?, isChecked: Boolean) {
        // do something
    }
})
```

- [Official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/fun-interfaces.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the best answer because you went into detail about what actually happens under the hood with your last piece of code. Most beginner books teaching android programming don't go into this level of detail. They think beginners are all Enstein.